# Is it possible to add image behind doughnut chart with transparency color in ng2chart?

Tags: angular, highcharts, chart.js, ng2-charts, angular-animations

I have the requirement to add image behind ng2 doughnut chart with transparency color, the image will be in doughnut chart  behind the color and not beyond that and not center of doughnut chart. is it possible to do it programtically. it is  single image .
AnyOne help appreciated.

```
Here is  plunker demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/lxwEBXQXseUrE6BsHI9h?p=preview
```

chart with transparency:

[image]
output be like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Background in Highcharts is an SVG element, so if you want to add image background to it you should apply `defs` pattern:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    var chart = this,
      renderer = chart.renderer,
      bg = chart.plotBackground;

    var pattern = renderer.createElement('pattern').add(renderer.defs).attr({
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
      id: 'bg-pattern',
      patternContentUnits: 'objectBoundingBox'
    });

    renderer.image('https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/15981345?s=400&v=4', 0, 0, 1, 1).attr({}).add(pattern);

    bg.css({
      color: 'url(#bg-pattern)'
    });
  }
}
```

Points opacity can be set via **CSS**:

```
.highcharts-point {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/694gs6qv/

---

**Docs reference:**
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer